# Delete or change google-services.json file

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have some conflict in my google-services.json file because of that I want to change the json file to another I couldn't delete the file I ve searched a lot . I couldn't find the answer . What the solution for it.

Comment: You don't have to delete the file. Just open it in Android Studio and open the new one (in some text editor) and replace all the code inside with new json code with simple copy-paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That json file referenced in android-studio cache so once close your android studio and then delete this file it will delete.. Hope it will help you...

Comment: So  I should close entire Android studio isn't it. I am working on 2 apps . So i closed one app that causes this pb . Now I got it. thank you!

Comment: if this case close that particular project

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**: just download the content of newly generated  google-services.json.

**step 2**: paste the content to file using inside your project.

**step 3**: Clean project -> Rebuild project

This will work!

Comment: Yes indeed but the point of this question is that although OP has overwritten the file, Android studio still uses the old one.

Comment: No, that's what I mean. Even if you overwrite the file (or manually change its content), Android Studio will STILL use the old one that doesn't exist anymore. You will have to restart Android Studio for it to use the new one.

Comment: ok, but cleaning then rebuilding the project will work.

Comment: Not for me, but its not important if you try it and if it doesnt work then you try something else